# Javascript / Typescript: Compare Date, string, and Moment variables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs, angular10

I am comparing two date variables.

For whatever reason, from C# API to Javascript, they sometimes convert as 1) `string` or 2) `Date` or even 3) `Moment` due to previous company code.

Typescript states they are `Date` in interface below, but in Javascript runtime, it changes.

So now, in comparing two dates, is there an easy way to simplify code below?
Converting everything to Date, and conducting `getTime()` comparison.

```
export interface Product {
    productName?: string;
    recordDate?: Date;
}

if (product1.recordDate instanceof Date) {
    dateVar1 = product1.recordDate;
} else if (typeof product1.recordDate === 'string') || product1.recordDate instanceof String)) {
    dateVar1 = new Date(product1.recordDate);
} else if (product1.recordDate instanceof moment) {
    dateVar1 = ((product1.recordDate as any) as moment.Moment).toDate();
}

if (product2.recordDate instanceof Date) {
    date2Var = product2.recordDate;
} else if (typeof product2.recordDate === 'string') || product2.recordDate instanceof String)) {
    date2Var = new Date(product2.recordDate);
} else if (product2.recordDate instanceof moment) {
    date2Var = ((product2.recordDate as any) as moment.Moment).toDate();
}


if date1Var.getTime() === date2Var.getTime() {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

using Angular environment ,

**Resources:**

[Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Moment`. Just pass `string` or `Date` or `Moment` value:

```js
dateVar1 = moment(product1.recordDate).toDate();
```

**Working Example**

```js
const stringDate = "2020-08-01";  // string
const dateDate = new Date();      // Date
const momentDate = moment();      // Moment

console.log(moment(stringDate).toDate());
console.log(moment(dateDate).toDate());
console.log(moment(momentDate).toDate());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```